# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns NULL values

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bitmapfactory, webp

This function returns Null in some images, the image extension is webp, in the emulator and I don't have problems, but one client has a Lenovo S6000 and some pages return NULL values...

The question is: Does another method exist to read images from a given URL?  Somebody please help me.

```
    Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url, Integer type){
        int scale=1;
        Integer contW = containerWidth, contH = containerHeight;
        int width_tmp=1200, height_tmp=1600;
        final AndroidHttpClient client      = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        final HttpClient client2            = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpGet getRequest            = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response               = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(getRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            response = null;
            try{
                response = client2.execute(getRequest);
            }catch(Exception e2){
                System.out.println(e2);
                return null;
            }
        }

        try{
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                System.out.println("Status error ");
                return null;
            }
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity == null){
                System.out.println("httpentity error ");
                return null;
            }               
            if(contH==0 || contW==0){
                scale = 5;
                contW = width_tmp;
                contH = height_tmp;
            }
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=Math.min(contH, contW);
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale++;
            }

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize=scale;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            options.inTargetDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;  
            options.inPurgeable=true;
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

            InputStream inputStream             = null;
            BufferedInputStream buffer          = null;
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity   = null;
            Bitmap img                          = null;

            try {
                if(type==0){
                    bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    inputStream = bufferedEntity.getContent();
                }else{
                    inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                }
                buffer=new BufferedInputStream(inputStream,16*1024);
                img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer,null,options);
                if (img != null && inputStream != null)             inputStream.close();
                if(buffer != null)                  buffer.close();
                if(bufferedEntity != null)          bufferedEntity.consumeContent();
                if(img != null && entity != null)   entity.consumeContent();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                img = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                img = null;
                System.out.println(e);
            }catch(Exception e){
                img = null;
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            error += "--->METODO "+(type==0?"1":"3")+"--->";
            if(img != null) 
                return img;

            FlushedInputStream buffer2  = null;
            try {
                if(type==0)
                    inputStream.reset();
                buffer2 = new FlushedInputStream(inputStream);
                img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer2,null,options);
                if(inputStream != null)     inputStream.close();
                if(buffer2 != null)         buffer2.close();
                if(entity != null)  entity.consumeContent();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                img = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                img = null;
                System.out.println(e);
            }catch(Exception e){
                img = null;
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            error += "--->METODO "+(type==0?"2":"4")+"--->";
            if(img != null)
                return img;

        }finally{
            if (client != null)   client.close();
            getRequest.abort();
        }
        if(type==0)
            return downloadBitmap(url,1);

        error += "--->THE SAME--->";
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: can you check your log, and give some hint that it return null from which condition?

Comment: All of them ... and what comment I have no way of seeing the error console as it is a device of a client ... now understand the frustration

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I seem to have the same issue, but I'm unable to get my hands on a S6000.